# Send SMS through the Internet?

Tags: mobile-phone, sms

I have a prepaid plan on my phone, so it costs money each time I send or receive a SMS. Is there a way for me to send and receive SMS through the Internet rather than through my mobile carrier? There used to be a service called Teleflip that sounded pretty promising.

Answer (score 4):

Get a [Google Voice](http://www.google.com/voice) number if you're in the USA. You can text for free with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a site I just looked up: http://www.onlinetextmessage.com/ I tried sending an SMS to my cellphone and it worked.